Articles of Faith amount
Articles of Faith/Articles of Religion are brief statements of belief of a particular denomination. Growing up as a member of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints I only ever heard this in context of the LDS 13 Articles of Faith published in 1842. While attending a musical event (at a Baptist church?) I skimmed through a book and found that they had Articles of Faith too. Having never heard another Christian bring up Articles of Faith in conversation, I've since then looked up a variety of articles, here are a few:

22 Articles of Religion: Wesleyan Church (1844)1
28 Articles of Faith: Bible Fellowship Church (founded 1858)
25 Articles of Religion: Methodist Church (1784)2

The earliest Article of Religion I believe is Thirty-nine Articles: The Church of England (1571)
Do any Christian denominations have more than 39 defined Articles of Religion? Do any have fewer than 13?
1 History of the Wesleyan Church
2 Britannica: Twenty-five Articles of Religion

The most often referenced collection of articles in Protestantism is the Westminster Confession of Faith 1646 and the very similar Savoy Declaration 1658. Up-voted +1.

33 and 32 respectively, for those counting

The Apostles' Creed and Nicene Creed are the oldest codified articles of faith. They predate the Church of England by over 1000 years.

@jaredad7 maybe? Feel free to answer,  I feel like there is a difference between creeds and articles of religion

The Westminster Confession has 33 chapters, but each can have many articles, most between 4-8, but chapter 1 has 10. You should compare the word count if you want to know the longest.

@curiousdannii you can provide an answer to that effect, longest/shortest by word count. That would be interesting to compare

The Westminster Confession (Church of Scotland et al) is arguably a different genre from the 39 Articles (Church of England et al). The WCF, like the even longer Catechism of the RCC, is a systematic exposition of the Christian Faith. The 39 Articles are less systematic, more "controversial", in the sense that they deal with matters of controversy, from ancient times until the sixteenth century, and state the C of E position on them. OP defines articles as "brief". What is the longest brief statement of faith, is like who's the smallest giant. WCF/RCC catechism-Articles-Creeds spectrum.

The shortest 7

Trinity Church

The longest 39 (42 in 15531)

The Church of England


non denomination

4 Linfield Christian school

non Christian

Islam: 6-72

bullets in case of tie
1 Forty-two Articles
2 Islam's 7 Articles of Faith

The Dutch reformed churches share the three "formulieren van eenigheid", the three "forms of unity". You can find them in English through wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Forms_of_Unity
Together they have many more articles than 39.
You could also consider the Catechism of the Catholic Church as a list of articles of the faith, I think. We are talking about many more than 39 in that case

Don't all denominations have some similar list of doctrinal positions?
Does it need to be called "Articles of Faith"?
If not, here are two more:

Official Statement of Fundamental Beliefs | Living Church of God — 29
Fundamental Beliefs of the United Church of God | United Church of God — 20

